# How to add values to a map within a for loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Considering this code:

```
T = table(categorical({'M';'F';'M'}),[45;32;34],logical([1;0;0]),...
          'VariableNames',{'Gender','Age','Vote'},...
          'RowNames',{'NY';'CA';'MA'});
M = containers.Map('KeyType','int32','ValueType','any');
M(1) = T;
```

Now, I want to extend the values by adding another table (here it's the same table) in the map `M` within a loop to an existing key. I've tried:

```
for i=1:5
    if isKey(M, 1)
        cur_content = M.values;
        cur_content{end+1} = T;
        M(1) = cur_content;
    end
end
```

So, my expected content in the map should be looking like this:

```
Key: 1, {table_1}, {table_2}, {table_3}, {table_4}, {table_5}
Key: n, {table_1}, ... {table_k}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you want to have a cell array as value assigned to key:

```
M(1) = {T};
```

Next, you want to extend this cell array, not the internal `values` array of the map:

```
cur = M(1);
cur{end+1} = T;
M(1) = cur;
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: M(1){end+1} = T; This is not a valid matlab expression. I get this error: Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression. I'm on Matlab R2017b.

Comment: @PythonNoob: You’re absolutely right. This should fix it.

Comment: Works! Thanks you.